# F# Pipeline operator into an indexer property?

Tags: f#, pipeline

How should one pipeline an index into an indexer property of eg.: a Map?

```
let aMap = [
    (1,'a')
    (2,'b')
    ] |> Map.ofList

let someChar =
    1
    |> aMap.Item
```

In the example above, I get the error that "An indexer property must be given at least one argument"

The following works, but in real code gets kind of ugly and strange looking. Is there a better way? What is the language reason for not accepting the pipelined item for the indexer property? is it because it is a getter property instead of a simple method?

```
let someChar =
    1
    |> fun index -> aMap.[index]
```

Edit: below is a better representation of the actual usage scenario with the solution I went with inside a transformation pipeline eg.:

```
let data =
    someList
    |> List.map (fun i ->
        getIndexFromData i
        |> Map.find <| aMap
        |> someOtherFunctionOnTheData
        )
    |> (*...*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't pipeline into an indexer property. Use indexers explicitly.

For F# collections modules, there usually exists a lookup function that can be used instead of index access (`Array.get`, `Map.find`, `Set.contains`).

Answer (score 2):

The `Item` indexer actually has a an associated getter method `get_Item` which F# compiler wisely hides from the auto-completion so that people do not use it, but it does allow you to use it:

```
let aMap = 
  [ (1,'a')
    (2,'b') ] |> Map.ofList

let someChar =
  1 |> aMap.get_Item
```

That said, I cannot imagine a situation where I would want to do this. Pipelines make sense in cases where you're chaining multiple operations on the same data structure (list transformations, etc.), but using pipeline as a general mechanism for invoking an operation is just introducing a more cumbersome syntax for doing a simple thing.

The point of indexers is to make it clear that you are indexing into some collection. Using that directly makes your code much more readable:

```
let someChar = aMap.[1]
```

Comment: I mean, the actual case was just that, transforming a list of indices into a list of data records from a Map, which then get further transformed. At the end I went with something like `|> Map.find <| aMap`

Comment: Well, `x |> Map.find <| aMap` still looks much more complicated than `aMap.[x]`.

Comment: but the actual alternative to `|> Map.find <| aMap` would be `|> (fun i -> aMap.[i])` at which point I feel stupid because why define a new lambda expression when I can just use the provided Map.find function